# Disable autoplay of embedded videoplayer in UIWebView

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, playback

In a UIWebView controller, sometimes, I'd like to link to a video. Problem is, I can't prevent the embedded video player from auto starting. Similar questions I found all seem to have issues playing YouTube videos, but that is not the case. I also tried to disable auto play by setting mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to NO, but that won't work.

Here's a sample of the my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
         <iframe src="http://eredivisielive.nl/player/TWE/play/131667/620" border="0" height="350" width="620"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Are there any sort of notifications I can observe to prevent videos from auto starting?

Comment: If the video is linked, why would you expect that clicking on the link would not play the video?  The only other thing you could do is catch the UIWebView link click and start your own instance of MPMediaPlayerController `initWithContentURL` and then set `shouldAutoPlay` to NO.

Comment: Maybe the example HTML doesn't reflect the issue very well. The video in the iframe is part of an article. So, when the web view loads, the user sees the article, but it immediately disappears as the video starts. Your answer however gave me a new insight, I'm going to try to parse the URL and create a MPMediaPlayerController manually, thanks :)